# How to get all the files from Internal and External Storage Programatically?

Tags: android-external-storage, internal-storage

I want to show device files in a list view and also want to delete files from list view. For this i am trying to get Images, Music and Video files from External and Internal both storage. But it's returning systems file also. I don't need to show system's file.
Please help.....